# trigger events after an ajax request with jquery

Tags: jquery, triggers, document-ready

I have a html page which contain a jQuery script and a AJAX request. On my page I have some span elements with the class 'loading_span'. On a click to a href, an ajax process is executed. That process also generates some spans with the class: 'loading_span'. The problem is that my jQuery script doesn't trigger the new added span elemnts by the ajax request.

The queswtion is: Why my script doesn't see that new element with class 'loading_span' were added?

In the followong I'll paste my code:

```
/* file js/javascript.js */
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false
    });

    $('#show-more').click( function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        success: function(msg){
            $('#all_span').append().html(msg);
        },
        dataType: "Html"
    });
    return false;
});


    $('.loading_span').each(function(index, span){
        console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
```

the index.php file:

```
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/script.js" ></script>   
        <style type="text/css">
            .loading_span {
                display: list-item;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="all_span">
        <?php

        for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
            echo "<span class='loading_span' id='id$i'>span$i</span>";
        ?>
            <a href="ajax.php" id="show-more">show_more</a>
        </div>
    </body>
```

and the ajax.pho file content

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
    echo "<span class='loading_span' id='ajax$i'>ajax$i</span>";
```

Comment: Are you asking why the code you have (`$('.loading_span').each...`) doesn't catch them?

Comment: @j08691: That's right. That is my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
$('#all_span').append(msg);
```

instead of

```
$('#all_span').append().html(msg);
```

and change your success callback to

```
success: function(msg){
        $('#all_span').append(msg);
        $('.loading_span').each(function(index, span){
            console.log($(this).attr('id'));
        });
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use after element to add element after loading_span.

See below url for just Javascript part. 
http://jsfiddle.net/vkTHK/1/

I still cannot figure out what you are trying to achieve. if it does not satisfy your need please elaborate on part or provide JS fiddle URL so i can help.

Comment: TY for your reply, but I need to apply the function from $('.loading_span').each();

Answer (score 0):

Your `$('.loading_span').each...` is executing prior to your AJAX call finishing which is why it's doing what it's doing. You can move that code into the `success` event of your AJAX call so it will be applied once the new elements are added to the DOM.